# proxy環境にてXcodeからGitHubへのpushでエラー

Tags: xcode, macos, github

proxy環境にてXcodeからGitHubへのpushで以下のエラーとなりました。

```
curl error: Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out (-1)
```

原因、解決方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

**動作環境**
  Xcode 9.2
  macOS 10.12.6

- macのネットワーク環境設定のプロキシは設定しています。
- XcodeのSource Control navigatorのRemotesは設定しています。
- Xcodeにてpull, cloneは実行できます。
- .gitconfigは以下のような感じで設定しています。

  ```
  $ cat ~/.gitconfig
  [https]
  proxy = http://{proxy server}:{port}
  [http]
  proxy = http://{proxy server}:{port}
  [user]
  name = {user}
  ```
- GitHub Desktop, Atomでは、pull, pushは問題なく動作しているので、gitconfigは効いていると思います。
- .curlrcは以下のような感じで設定しています。

  ```
  $ cat ~/.curlrc
  proxy = http://{proxy server}:{port}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

.gitconfigにはuser情報がありますが、.curlrcにはありません。どちらの設定が正しいでしょうか？
また、443ですので証明書関連などはないでしょうか？そもそもアクセスできないのなら、
ほかのエラーがでそうです。

以上